# Replacing strings in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, replace

I have those strings in y table:

abcdefg_1056-DF or
123erttzz-1292 or 
gdfgdfg_1056

What I want is only the first part, *abcdefg* for example for the first string. So I can replace all numbers and all -DF with an empty string, but I dont know how.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a regex replace. Have a look here - I think this might help you:

[How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

If you prever a lazy and ugly method (and not recommended for very, very much rows), you can spare yourself a user defined function like in mwerner's answer and do it simply like this:

```
select 
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(asdf, '0', ''), '1', ''), '2', ''), '3', ''), '4', ''), '5', ''), '6', ''), '7', ''), '8', ''), '9', ''), '_', ''), '-DF', '')
from
(
select
'abcdefg_1056-DF' as asdf
union select
'123erttzz-1292'
union select
'gdfgdfg_1056'
)q
```